# Mysterious issue with Google Chrome, BIRT and WebSphere

Tags: google-chrome, soap, websphere, birt

I have a web app which I deploy on Tomcat 6, Jetty 7 and WebSphere 7. It uses BIRT reporting. I use the following browsers for testing: Firefox 6, Google Chrome 14, IE 9.

All of these combinations work but one: Chrome with WebSphere.

When I try to view a report using this pair, I get a `SAXException: unexpected end of file` in [`org.apache.axis.SOAPPart` line 696](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/webservices/axis/branches/AXIS_1_4_FINAL/src/org/apache/axis/SOAPPart.java):

```
    DeserializationContext dser = new DeserializationContext(is,
                                       getMessage().getMessageContext(),
                                       getMessage().getMessageType());
    dser.getEnvelope().setOwnerDocument(this);
    // This may throw a SAXException
    try {
        dser.parse();  // <-- ERROR
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        Exception real = e.getException();
        if (real == null)
            real = e;
        throw AxisFault.makeFault(real);
    }
```

The input is an `InputStream` but it's an WebSphere implementation and I have no idea how I could get at the data. I can see what the browser sends to the server but that looks fine to me (indented for easier reading):

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <GetUpdatedObjects xmlns="http://schemas.eclipse.org/birt">
            <Operation>
                <Target>
                    <Id>Document</Id>
                    <Type>Document</Type>
                </Target>
                <Operator>GetPage</Operator>
                <Oprand>
                    <Name>Stichtag</Name>
                    <Value></Value>
                </Oprand>
                <Oprand>
                    <Name>__isdisplay__Stichtag</Name>
                    <Value></Value>
                </Oprand>
                <Oprand>
                    <Name>__page</Name>
                    <Value>1</Value>
                </Oprand>
                <Oprand>
                    <Name>__svg</Name>
                    <Value>false</Value>
                </Oprand>
                <Oprand>
                    <Name>__page</Name>
                    <Value>1</Value>
                </Oprand>
                <Oprand>
                    <Name>__taskid</Name>
                    <Value>2011-8-21-12-36-37-692</Value>
                </Oprand>
            </Operation>
        </GetUpdatedObjects>
    </Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I tried to debug this but the runtime sax parser has no debug information.

Any ideas what I could try?